# How to direct a link to a page, and not a directory?

Tags: html, .htaccess

I'm trying out the whole "remove html from url via .htaccess" method, and to complete it, i have to direct my links to the pages without the ".html" extension, however a problem is that there are directories with the same name as the pages (such as a folder named "games" as well as a .html file called "games"), and because of that, the links redirect to the directory folders and not the .html pages. I tried rewriting the .htaccess file so that the .html extension is removed from the url without re-writing the links, but it does the same thing, opening the directory folders of the same name.
So what would i have to do to fix this issue? i could try renaming all of my directories, but there is too many of them to do so. I apologize if this question seems oblivious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding "_"games to the .html?

Comment: I tried on the directory folders instead and it worked, thanks.